# El nombre no existe en el espacio de nombres "clr-namespace:"

Tags: visual-studio, wpf, excepciones, visual-studio-2019

Tenía en mi PC un proyecto de WPF que hice en Visual Studio 2019 y lo subí ayer a un repositorio en Bonobo GIT Server.
El tema es que al clonar esta solución, cuando intento compilarla me da 10 errores que son todos muy parecidos.

> El nombre "VMLocator" no existe en el espacio de nombres "clr-namespace:UI.ViewModels"

Obviamente el espacio de nombres existe realmente y la clase también, las referencias a esta clase están correctas e incluso el `intellisense` lo reconoce. Si yo intento recompilar la solución original puedo hacerlo sin problema alguno, pero la que tengo en el repositorio  no hay forma, tengo 10 errores iguales a este pero con diferentes clases.

Ya busqué muchas formas de arreglar esto pero ninguna parece funcionar:
Reinicié varias veces Visual Studio.
**No funcionó**

Seguí estos pasos:
1- Si la plataforma de compilación actual es x64, cambie a x86. Si actualmente es x86, cambie a x64.
2- Solución Clean and Build para la nueva plataforma de destino.
3- Volver a cambiar a la plataforma de destino deseada y vuelva a construir.
**No funcionó**

Ejecutar el comando `devenv /resetuserdata` desde el Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019.
**No funcionó**

Eliminar todas las .dll de las carpetas `Debug` y `Release`.
**No funcionó**

Sinceramente ya no sé que más hacer.

Comment: No has cambiado el namespace de alguna clase o de tu proyecto recientemente? Ese es un error MUY típico cuando haces eso, siempre queda una que otra clase sin actualizar y que te jode la existencia.

Comment: No, incluso he vuelto a copiar el código del proyecto original y lo puse en el proyecto del repositorio y sigue igual... me está volviendo loco jajaja

Comment: A ver, si el código es el mismo de cuando funcionaba y ahora da problemas es claro que la configuración tiene un desajuste, talvez colocando en las propiedades "CUALQUIER CPU" podría funcionar, a lo mejor usaste DLL's de cierta versión y al restaurar Visual Studio descargó otras distintas, si tuviera la solución a mano podría resolverlo, yo creo que puedes probar cambiar de DEBUG a RELEASE y probar si en alguna te funciona

Comment: No sé cuál fue el problema realmente, pero lo que terminé haciendo fue borrar el repositorio y crearlo nuevamente... con eso lo solucioné

Comment: Mmmm talvez el IGNORE se llevó algunos archivos esenciales.